# how to set value of elrte editor?

Tags: jquery, html, editor, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

I'm working on a update page, and I want to set value of elrte, but how?

```
 <textarea id="ehtml"></textarea>
..
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ehtml').elrte(opts_edit);
    $('#ehtml').elrte('val') = $('#ehtml').val(); //not working error:  Invalid left-hand side in assignment
});
...
```

thanks.

Comment: try '$('#ehtml').find(elrte).val($('#ehtml').val());'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you should do:

```
 $('#ehtml').elrte('val', $('#ehtml').val() );
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#ehtml').elrte('val', $('#ehtml').val());
```

as found on http://elrte.org/redmine/projects/elrte/wiki/JavaScript_API_EN